# Overfitting with random forest though very successful cross validation results

Tags: python-2.7, random-forest, h2o

I have moderate experience with data science. I have a data set with 9500 observations and more than 4500 features most of which are highly correlated. Here is briefly what I have tried: I have dropped columns where there are less than 6000 non-NAs and have imputed NAs with their corresponding columns' median values when there are at least 6000 non-NAs. As for correlation, I have kept only features having at most 0.7 correlation with others. By doing so, I have reduced the number of features to about 750. Then I have used those features in my binary classification task in random forest.

My data set is highly unbalanced where ratio of (0:1) is (10:1). So when I apply RF with 10-fold cv, I observe too good results in each cv (AUC of 99%) which is to good to be true and in my test set I got way worse results such as 0.7. Here is my code:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators import H2ORandomForestEstimator

h2o.init(port=23, nthreads=4)

train = fs_rf[fs_rf['Year'] <= '201705']
test = fs_rf[fs_rf['Year'] > '201705']
train = train.drop('Year',axis=1)
test = test.drop('Year',axis=1)
test.head()

train = h2o.H2OFrame(train)
train['BestWorst2'] = train['BestWorst2'].asfactor()

test = h2o.H2OFrame(test)
test['BestWorst2'] = test['BestWorst2'].asfactor()

training_columns = train.drop('BestWorst2',axis=1).col_names
response_column = 'BestWorst2'

model = H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=100, max_depth=20, nfolds=10, balance_classes=True)

model.train(x=training_columns, y=response_column, training_frame=train)

performance = model.model_performance(test_data=test)

print(performance)
```

How could I avoid this over-fitting? I have tried many different parameters in grid search but none of them improved the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what I would call "overfitting".  The reason you are seeing really good cross-validation metrics compared to your test metrics is that you have time-series data and so you can't use k-fold cross-validation to give you an accurate estimate of performance.

Performing k-fold cross-validation on a time-series dataset will give you overly-optimistic performance metrics because you are not respecting the time-series component in your data. Regular k-fold cross-validation will randomly sample from your whole dataset to create a train & validation set. Essentially, your validation strategy is "cheating" because you have "future" data included in your CV training sets (if that makes any sense).

I can see by your code that you understand that you need to train with "past" data and predict on "future" data, but if you want to read more about this topic, I'd recommend this [article](http://www.fast.ai/2017/11/13/validation-sets) or this [article](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2017/02/28/whats-wrong-with-my-time-series/).

One solution is to simply look at test set performance as way to evaluate your model.  Another option is to use what's called "rolling" or "time-series" cross-validation, but H2O does not currently support that (though it seems like it might be added soon).  Here's a [ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3913) for this if you want to keep track of the progress.